# Hazelcast get list of column values

Tags: hazelcast

I want to get a list of column values instead of getting the whole IMap in hazelcast.
 Is it possible to get a list of column values in hazelcast? (Example : List which contains all the names of a Student from Student table)

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question with some sample data and exact requirement? Yes this can be achieved. But need details before I can suggest something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could build your own EntryProcessor extracting the column (property) you're interested in and send only this back. It would look like:

```
class MyExtractor extends AbstractEntryProcessor<String, User> {
  Object process(Map.Entry<String, User> entry) {
    return entry.getValue().getUsername();
  }
}

Map<String, Object> result = map.executeOnEntries(new MyExtractor());
```

I hope this helps and answers your question :)